# Vector Autoregression - Resource request

Tags: macroeconomics, econometrics

I am looking for resources that give a self-contained introduction to vector autoregression. To be a bit more specific, I am interested in VAR models and their application to isolating and investigating monetary policy shocks.

Comment: Almost a duplicate at Cross Validated: [What are good resources to learn about VAR models?](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/255939/what-are-good-resources-to-learn-about-var-models).

Comment: I am looking for a discussion of VARs in the context of evaluating monetary shocks. I have Hayashi for a purely statistical treatment.